# replace a value in csv file using java

Tags: java, csv

I want to update a particular column in csv if the condition is met.
For example

```
 engineer,i
 doctor,i
```

is the csv file,once the row is visited i want to change the "i" value to "v"

```
for(String line1 :lines)
{
    String[] array1 = line1.split(",");
    if(array1[1]=="v")
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        double distance = compute(array[0], array1[0]);
        if(distance>0.8)
        {
            lines1.add(line1);
            array1[1]="v"; //why this line doesnot update that column
        }
    }
}
```

so how to update or replace a value in csv file???

Comment: [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: `array1[1]="v"; //why this line doesnot update that column` The array is not linked to the CSV. You'll have to write it back to the file.

Comment: Uh... `1` make your code easy to read by removing the excessive indentation, and `2` are you asking us to read all the comments in the code to find out what's the question?

Comment: how to write it back to that file...i searched a lot but didnt get any answer 
   @shmosel

Comment: Strings are compared using `equals` function not `==` operator

Comment: we can compare it like that ,betweet that is not my problem,i just want to update the file @ali

Comment: check if `distance>0.8` passes and add this line at the end of your loop `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));`

Comment: Parsing CSV is trickier than it looks.  Use an existing, reliable CSV library like OpenCSV or Apache Commons CSV.

Comment: will netbeans 8 support openCSV @Jim